# Integral of a function with two parts (piecewise defined)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The function has 2 parts:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} -\sin x & x \le 0 \\ 2x & x > 0\end{cases}$$

I need to calculate the integral between $-\pi$ and $2$.
So is the answer is an integral bewteen $-\pi$ and $0$ of $f(x)$ and then and $0$ to $2$.
but why the calculation of the first part of $-\pi$ and $2$ aire on $-\sin x$ and the second part of the intgral is on $x^2$, which is part of the $F(x)$.

I'd like to get some help over here, I'm lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following fundamental property of integrals: if $f(x)$ is integrable on an interval $[a,b]$, and $c\in[a,b]$, then
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^c f(x) dx + \int_c^b f(x) dx.$$
In your case, you thus have
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^2 f(x) dx &= \int_{-\pi}^0 f(x) dx + \int_0^2 f(x) dx\\
&= \int_{-\pi}^0 -\sin(x) dx + \int_0^2 2x dx.\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Since your function for $x \le 0$ as $-\sin x$ and when $x >0$ your function is $2x$, you must split your integral.

**Your function is defined as two separate functions for specific domains. Therefore, we must satisfy the conditions by integrating within the right bounds.**

As we can see:

$$\int_{-\pi}^0 -\sin xdx + \int_{0}^2 2xdx$$

Now we integrate,

$$\int_{-\pi}^0 -\sin xdx =[\cos x]_{-\pi}^0 = 2$$

And

$$\int_{0}^2 2xdx = [x^2]_{0}^2 = 4$$

So our final answer is $$2 + 4 = 6$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$ \displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{2} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = \displaystyle\int_{-\pi}^{0} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x + \displaystyle\int_{0}^{2} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $$ *because* each integral is an area under the curve $f(x)$ under the given domain and we want to find the full area so we just add the two "components" of the area to get the total.